# How do I correct 'Unable to load class 'com.android.build.api.dsl.StoreArchive'.' error when i add firebase firestore to my android studio project

Tags: android, gradle

My project runs fine before i try to connect with firebase. I then go to `tools -> Firebase -> Connect your app to Firebase` and Add Cloud firestore to your app. After I select these options they say 'Connected' and 'Dependencies set up correctly'  but immediately after I get the following error:

```
"Unable to load class 'com.android.build.api.dsl.StoreArchive'."
```

I haven't tried anything as I can't work out where the error is.

Answer (score 9):

in `build.gradle` project level, downgrading from `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'` to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'` solved the probelm.

other related information in wrapper:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
```

Comment: It's so embarassing if you follow the google firebase instructions and just nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Same, I upgraded my android studio to the latest version and solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).